# This code seems to get stuck on the first while loop

Tags: arduino

I have this arduino code that seems to get stuck on the first while loop. What is wrong with it?
It is supposed to turn on a green, yellow, and red LED respectively depending on the voltage level from 1V to 5V.

0.01V - 2.9V is green led
3.0V - 3.9V is yellow led
4.0V - 5.0V is red led

```
int readPin = A1;
int readVal;
float Voltage;
int green = 8;
int yellow = 9;
int red = 10;
int delayT = 100;


 void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
 pinMode(A1, INPUT);
 pinMode(green, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(yellow, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(red, OUTPUT);
 }

 void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
 readVal = analogRead(readPin);
 Voltage = (readVal/1023.) * 5.;
 

while (Voltage >= 0.01 && Voltage < 3.0){
 digitalWrite(green, HIGH);
 Voltage = (readVal/1023.) * 5.;
 }
 digitalWrite(green, LOW);

while (Voltage >= 3.0 && Voltage < 4.0){
 digitalWrite(yellow, HIGH);
 Voltage = (readVal/1023.) * 5;
 }
 digitalWrite(yellow, LOW);

while (Voltage >= 4.0 && Voltage <= 5.0){
 digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
 Voltage = (readVal/1023.) * 5;
 }
 digitalWrite(red, LOW);

delay(delayT);

 }
```

Comment: In your own words, why should the result of `Voltage = (readVal/1023.) * 5.` ever go out of range? Why should it ever *change* within the while loop?

Comment: It shouldn't, thanks for the answer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your while loop, you're not updating the value of `readVal`, so it stays the same on every cycle of the while loop.

Consider adding  `readVal = analogRead(readPin);` inside the while loops!

Also.. you might not really need while loops, just do if statements to trigger  each condition:

```
void loop() {
 readVal = analogRead(readPin);
 Voltage = (readVal/1023.) * 5.;
 

if(Voltage >= 4.0 && Voltage <= 5.0){
 digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
 digitalWrite(green, LOW);
 digitalWrite(yellow, LOW);
 }
else if(Voltage >= 3.0 && Voltage < 4.0){
 digitalWrite(yellow, HIGH);
 digitalWrite(green, LOW);
 digitalWrite(read, LOW);
 }
else if (Voltage >= 0.01 && Voltage < 3.0){
 digitalWrite(green, HIGH);
 digitalWrite(red, LOW);
 digitalWrite(yellow, LOW);
 }



delay(delayT);

 }
```

and even better so you are not writing digitalWrite so frequently, add a simple condition to check if you really need to do a change at all:
(Note haven't run this code, but should work..)

```
enum Colors {OFF, RED, YELLOW, GREEN};

int currentColor = Colors::OFF;  

void loop() {
 readVal = analogRead(readPin);
 Voltage = (readVal/1023.) * 5.;
 
 int expectedColor = Colors::OFF;

// go through our voltage logic to figure out the expected color
if(Voltage >= 4.0 && Voltage <= 5.0){
 expectedColor  = Colors::RED;
 }
else if(Voltage >= 3.0 && Voltage < 4.0){
 expectedColor  = Colors::YELLOW;
 }
else if (Voltage >= 0.01 && Voltage < 3.0){
 expectedColor  = Colors::GREEN;
 }

// we only want to call digitalWrite if the currentColor is not the
// color we expect, and we want to write the color we do expect
// (which is expectedColor.)

if (expectedColor != currentColor) {

 currentColor = expectedColor;

 digitalWrite(red, currentColor == Colors::RED ? HIGH : LOW);
 digitalWrite(green, currentColor == Colors::GREEN? HIGH : LOW);
 digitalWrite(yellow, currentColor == Colors::YELLOW ? HIGH : LOW);

}

delay(delayT);

 }
```

Explanation:

`enum Colors {OFF, RED, YELLOW, GREEN};`

we can use an enum as a set of possible states for your LED's
an enum has a name (e.g. Colors) and by default,
the states are type integer, so OFF=0, RED=1, YELLOW=2, GREEN=3,
and so on, you can keep adding new colors if you like.
you can access an enum using Colors::RED or Colors::YELLOW, etc..

`int currentColor = Colors::OFF;`

we begin in the OFF state. Note that the arduino doesn't really
know what OFF is, this is something we define that is not RED,
YELLOW or GREEN.

`int expectedColor = Colors::OFF;`

initialize a second variable to compare the current loop cycle's
expected color with the currentColor later

`digitalWrite(red, currentColor == Colors::RED ? HIGH : LOW);`

the only tricky part here is the ternary operator
a ternary operator is a shortcut for an if statement
a ternary operator goes like this:
condition ? value if true : value if false
for red, we ask the question "is currentColor == RED?" if true,
then we set it to high. if false, we set it to false.
if the voltage should make the currentColor RED, then for the
green operator we ask the question "is currentColor == GREEN?",
the answer is no, currentColor is red, so we write LOW for green pin

Comment: last example: nvm, ran it on an online compiler, works just fine!

Comment: Thank you for this answer! It solved my problem. As for the last block of code, I am still trying to understand what is going on.

Comment: I got it! Very clever!

Comment: I'm glad you got it. I added inline comments to clarify last example more too :)